# Error with input form with a json field in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4.2 app with postgres, the field `ui_layout` is converted into `json` in the db table (psql supports json data type). The `ui_layout` used to be a `text` field. After converting `ui_layout` to `json` in db table, the rendering of the input form `new` returns an error as below:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No input found for json):
    48:                         <%= f.input :footer, :label => ('Footer') %>
    49:                         <%= f.input :time_periods, :label => ('Time Periods') %>
    50:                         <%= f.input :max_time_period, :label => ('max Time Period') %>
    51:                         <%= f.input :ui_layout, :label => ('UI Layout (json)'), :input_html => {:rows => 2} %>
    52:
    53:
    54:                         <div class="btn-toolbar" >
  simple_form (3.1.1) lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb:574:in `find_mapping'
  simple_form (3.1.1) lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb:503:in `find_input'
  simple_form (3.1.1) lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb:113:in `input'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/onboard_data_uploadx-f2c20c94f7d6/app/views/onboard_data_uploadx/dashboard_details/_form_new.html.erb:51:in `block in __home_ubuntu__rvm_gems_ruby_______bundler_gems_onboard_data_uploadx_f_c__c__f_d__app_views_onboard_data_uploadx_dashboard_details__form_new_html_erb__2939072899287253628_79696400'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'
```

On the `new` input form, the `ui_layout` is treated as `text` field. What's the right way to enter to a `json` field? Do I need to take a text input and convert it into `json` in controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ActionView::Template::Error (No input found for json)

By natively, `simple_form` **doesn't support** *JSON datatype*. However you can *overwrite the input type* which should resolve the problem

```
<%= f.input :ui_layout, as: :text, :label => ('UI Layout (json)'), :input_html => {:rows => 2} %>
```